# How to use RestSharp for non standard url containing symbols like = and ::?

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I have to call the following URL using RestSharp.
Some part of the uri are not standard.
How can I get to use them in

The url is the following but without the white space:
http:// mysite.com/api/v2.php?method **=** information **::** method&token=b&target_id=0

I've tried something like this but RestSharp is not calling the URL I was expecting to call.

```
var client2 = new RestClient("http:// mysite.com/api/v2.php");
var request = new RestRequest("method=information::method", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("token", authenticationToken);
request.AddParameter("target_id", targetId);
```

Comment: This is __literally__ an exact duplicate -- character for character -- of [a question you deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761320/how-to-use-restsharp-for-non-standard-url-containing-symbols-like-and) after it got closed. You've already been warned about this. Do not do it again.

Comment: @Pops: yes.. sorry I'm banned on Meta so I can't answer you there. I think the question was closed for bad reason. As you can see yourself "this literally duplicate" is completely ok. Now I got an answer which can be useful for many people as well. Can you also warn who voted to close the first answer for their unproper use of SE?

Comment: ps: I need to speak with a moderator in chat, can you help me?

Comment: Sorry Sam, I was out of town, then sick. Do you still want to talk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what url your code actually calls, but I guess that your method is parsed as a file/path, and not a parameter.

```
var client = new RestClient("http:// mysite.com/api/");
var request = new RestRequest("v2.php", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("method", "information::method");
request.AddParameter("token", authenticationToken);
request.AddParameter("target_id", targetId);
```